# How do I produce a horizontal space the size of an underbracket?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, underbrace

I have an equation that is too long to fit on one line, so I put a few terms on a second line using `amsmath`'s `aligned` environment. However, the first line of the equation contains an underbrace that causes the second line to be placed too far down below the original equation, like so:

[image: too much space]

I was able to reduce the gap by eye using a negative space after the first line break, but I would like to know how to reduce the gap in a way such that the spacing between the first and second line remains **exactly** the same as it would be without the underbrace, like this:

[image: ideal spacing]

I believe that the answer to my question involves getting the height of just the underbrace without the text above and inserting a negative space of that magnitude after the first line break, but I'm not sure how to do it.

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        P(\underbrace{C_{t}^{d}+I_{t}^{d}+G_{t}^{d}}_{=Y_{t}^{d}}-Y_{t}^{s})+\left(B_{t}^{p}+B_{t}^{g}\right)+\left(M_{t}^{d}-M_{t}^{s}\right)&=\left(1+r_{t-1}\right)\left(B_{t-1}^{p}+B_{t-1}^{g}\right)\\
        &+\left(M_{t-1}^{d}-M_{t-1}^{s}\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please compare:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


You have:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        P(\underbrace{C_{t}^{d}+I_{t}^{d}+G_{t}^{d}}_{=Y_{t}^{d}}-Y_{t}^{s})+\left(B_{t}^{p}+B_{t}^{g}\right)+\left(M_{t}^{d}-M_{t}^{s}\right)&=\left(1+r_{t-1}\right)\left(B_{t-1}^{p}+B_{t-1}^{g}\right)\\
        &+\left(M_{t-1}^{d}-M_{t-1}^{s}\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

You want:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        P(\smash{\underbrace{C_{t}^{d}+I_{t}^{d}+G_{t}^{d}}_{=Y_{t}^{d}}}-Y_{t}^{s})+\left(B_{t}^{p}+B_{t}^{g}\right)+\left(M_{t}^{d}-M_{t}^{s}\right)&=\left(1+r_{t-1}\right)\left(B_{t-1}^{p}+B_{t-1}^{g}\right)\\
        &+\left(M_{t-1}^{d}-M_{t-1}^{s}\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
or rather
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        P(\smash{\underbrace{C_{t}^{d}+I_{t}^{d}+G_{t}^{d}}_{=Y_{t}^{d}}}-Y_{t}^{s})+\left(B_{t}^{p}+B_{t}^{g}\right)+\left(M_{t}^{d}-M_{t}^{s}\right)&=\left(1+r_{t-1}\right)\left(B_{t-1}^{p}+B_{t-1}^{g}\right)\\
        &\qquad+\left(M_{t-1}^{d}-M_{t-1}^{s}\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The final indentation improves the readability.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks.